# Which gerber file to use for pcb maker

Tags: electrical-engineering

I have a PCB maker at school, but no one really knows how it works, because it's a pretty old thing. I asked for the instruction manual and it turns out, the manual is also pretty old. If i want to import my **gerber** file the manual says I should import these files:
[image]

Now, I'm not really sure if this is the right place to ask, but I don't have a **.TOP .BOT .BOA** or **.DRD**. These are the files in my gerber zipfile:

[image]

So, my question, which files am I supposed to import to the PCB. (By the way, the PCB maker is a LPKF Protomat s62)

Answer (score 1):

I think the thing to know here is that the file extensions of Gerber files are not standardized. Some programs use the extension to indicate the layer, and others just include the layer in the filename. To this day, when you upload Gerbers to PCB fab services, they often mis-identify which layers are which.

With all the extension confusion, it's sometimes difficult to know if your files even *are* gerbers. For example, the drill file is usally not a gerber, but rather a "NC drill" file type.

The easiest way to handle this is not worry about the file extensions too much, and just make sure you have your own consistent system for keeping track of what's what.

Almost every PCB manufactuerer will require the following (using a 2 layer board as an example):

- Top Silk Screen Gerber
- Top Solder Mask Gerber
- Top Copper Gerber
- Bottom Copper Gerber
- Bottom Solder Mask Gerber
- Bottom Silk Gerber
- Board Outline Gerber
- NC Drill File

The extension doesn't matter, a gerber is a gerber (except the NC drill file).